# Apache Sling Content Module Wrapper

Tags: java, apache, aem, sling

I am implementing a website with apache sling. Some parts should be "editable".

[image]

So I created a custom Filter which is wrapping the resource with some markup providing the edit options and the module specific form to change the properties. So far so good.

```
@SlingFilter(scope = INCLUDE, order = 0)
public class EditContentFilter implements Filter
{
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
{
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = (SlingHttpServletRequest) request;

    Resource resource = slingRequest.getResource();

    if (isComponent(resource))
    {
        response.getWriter().write(this.buildEditBarHTML(resource));
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        response.getWriter().write("</div>");
    }
    else
    {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

```
private String buildEditBarHTML(Resource resource)
{

    ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resource.getResourceResolver();
    Resource componentResource = resourceResolver.resolve("/apps/" + resource.getResourceType());
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder("<div class='editable' data-resource='" + resource.getPath() + "'>");
    if (componentResource != null)
    {
        Resource componentDialog = componentResource.getChild("form");
        if (componentDialog != null)
        {
            Iterable<Resource> dialogItems = componentDialog.getChildren();

            html.append("<div class='edit-pannel'><span class='btn btn-primary edit-component' onclick=\"openDialog('").append(this.buildDialogId(resource.getPath())).append("')\">edit</span><a href='#' class='btn btn-danger'>delete</a></div>");
            html.append("<div id=\"").append(this.buildDialogId(resource.getPath())).append("\" class=\"overlay\">");
            html.append("<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"closebtn\" onclick=\"closeDialog('").append(this.buildDialogId(resource.getPath())).append("')\">&times;</a>");
            html.append("<div class=\"overlay-content\">");
            html.append("<form class=\"form-inline\" method=\"post\" action=\"#\">");
            for (Resource dialogItem : dialogItems)
            {
                html.append(buildDialogItem(dialogItem));
            }
            html.append("<button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">save</button>");
            html.append("</form>");
            html.append("</div>");
        }
        else
        {
            html.append("<div class='edit-pannel'><span class='btn btn-info disabled edit-component'>edit</span><a href='#' class='btn btn-danger'>delete</a></div>");
        }
    }
    html.append("</div>");
    return html.toString();
}
```

Everything is working fine. But I really don't like to create that markup manually with my java backend code.

So I thought its a good idea to create a component that is generating the edit panel and then includes the actual component. Something like this.

```
<div class='editable' data-resource="${resource.path}">
<!-- Edit Pannel -->
<sly data-sly-resource="${resource.path @ resourceType='website/dialog/editPanel'}"></sly>

<!-- Include component -->
<sly data-sly-resource="${resource.path}"></sly>

<!-- Edit Overlay -->
<sly data-sly-resource="${resource.path @ resourceType='website/dialog/editOverlay'}"></sly>
</div>
```

But I have no idea how to overwrite the resource type on the Filter.
Does anyone of you have any idea to solve that?